# shell script not running using crontab

Tags: shell, shell-script, cron

This is my script

```
mboxutil -l > n.txt
sed 's/^.*user//' n.txt > n1.txt
cat n1.txt | sed 's/^.//' > n2.txt
sed 's/\/.*//' n2.txt > dss_list.txt
rm -f n.txt
rm -f n1.txt
rm -f n2.txt

sed -e '/^$/d' -e '1d' dss_list.txt > all-dss-accounts.txt
rm -f dss_list.txt
CNT=`wc -l < all-dss-accounts.txt`
mailx -s "DSS count on `date` is $CNT" karthik@email.com < all-dss-accounts.txt
```

When I run the script directly, it executes.
But on crontab, it doesn't execute correctly.

This is the cron entry.

```
10 14,16,18,20,22 29 6 * /root/scripts/extract.sh
```

10th minute of 2PM,4PM,6PM,8PM,10PM on 29th of June every month.

I'm not sure but I have a feeling that the .txt files i'm creating temporarily using the script needs to contain the directory under which it needs to be created.

Am I right? Help me!

Comment: Do you have permission to write in root  home? Is this a root crontab?

Comment: In which exact line does your program stop? What is incorrect?

Comment: @tachomi - yes, i run it in root. i have root access. 
@Anthon, - it doesn't execute this one.
CNT=`wc -l < all-dss-accounts.txt`
It returns the value as 0. But actually when i run it directly, it returns the exact value of CNT.

Comment: @Karthik Try writing an error log to see if there is an error output. Try `10 14,16,18,20,22 29 6 * /root/scripts/extract.sh > output.log 2>&1`

Comment: @tachomi - this is the error it recorded in output.log `/root/scripts/extract.sh: mboxutil: not found
Can't open /root/kakanara/n.txt
` But i fail to understand why it works perfectly when i just run ./extract.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use full paths to ensure the functionality.

In the `mboxutil` situation, you must know where's the command located.

Execute:

```
$ type -a mboxutil
mboxutil is hashed /opt/sun/comms/messaging64/bin/mboxutil
```

Update your script:

```
/opt/sun/comms/messaging64/bin/mboxutil -l > /path/to/n.txt
sed 's/^.*user//' /path/to/n.txt > /path/to/n1.txt
cat /path/to/n1.txt | sed 's/^.//' > /path/to/n2.txt
sed 's/\/.*//' /path/to/n2.txt > /path/to/dss_list.txt
rm -f /path/to/n.txt
rm -f /path/to/n1.txt
rm -f /path/to/n2.txt

sed -e '/^$/d' -e '1d' /path/to/dss_list.txt > /path/to/all-dss-accounts.txt
rm -f /path/to/dss_list.txt
CNT=`wc -l < /path/to/all-dss-accounts.txt`
cat /path/to/all-dss-accounts.txt | mail -s "DSS count on `date` is $CNT" karthik@email.com
```

To skip file permission issues add the following `chmod` line at the very end of the script

```
chmod 777 /path/to/all-dss-accounts.txt
```

Give a try!

Comment: I used `echo $0` & got this `-sh`. Also, using the shebang at the first line didn't help me

Comment: @Karthik Type `whereis  mboxutil` and tell me what's the output

Comment: Hi Tachomi, when i typed `whereis mboxutil` i got this response `whereis: not found`. I'm clueless now as what is wrong!

Comment: @Karthik What SO you're using? Are you executing the `whereis` command as root? Please try executing also `echo $PATH` and let me know the output

Comment: Yes, I'm executing the whereis command as root. `echo $PATH` gives me this - `/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/X/bin:/opt/sun/comms/messaging64/lib:/opt/sun/comms/messaging64/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/root/bs`

Comment: @Karthik Ok, our target is to know where is located the `mboxutil` command so we can put the path as the shebang. Have you tried setting the output of `echo $0` as the shebang?

Comment: `echo $SHELL` gave me the path `/sbin/sh`. I used it as the shebang (`#!/sbin/sh`) and scheduled the script on crontab as `12 07 7 7 * /root/kakanara/extract.sh > output.log 2>&1`. It again failed to give me the count. Running the script directly without using cron gave me the correct count. The output.log says this - `/root/scripts/extract.sh: mboxutil: not found` `Can't open /root/scripts/n.txt`. `/root/scripts/` is the path where my original file `extract.sh` is placed.

Comment: @Karthik Lets try this: We still don't know where the `mboxutil` command is placed, considering it is a command, let see what is its PATH. Execute `type -a mboxutil`, the output will give you the right path, put that as the shebang. By the way, can you execute the `mboxutil -l > n.txt` line in command line? What does the `mboxutil` function is? What S.O. you're using?

Comment: `mboxutil -l > n.txt` works perfectly in the command line. Like i've said, the script works perfect when I run it directly. Issue arises only when I schedule it on the crontab. This `mboxutil` actually fetches some data from the mail servers which I further refine using my script to generate a report.

Comment: `type -a mboxutil` gives me `-a not found` `mboxutil is hashed (/opt/sun/comms/messaging64/bin/mboxutil)`. Not sure if I can use this path `/opt/sun/comms/messaging64/bin/mboxutil` as shebang.

Comment: @Karthik Try using it as the shebang, also try setting full paths  in the script as `/opt/sun/comms/messaging64/bin/mboxutil -l > n.txt` both must work. As you could see when typing echo $PATH the `/opt/sun/comms/messaging64/bin/mboxutil` appears in the output, that's why you could execute it manualy

Comment: @Karthik Don't use it as the shebang, write the full path

Comment: `echo $PATH` gives me `/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/X/bin:/opt/sun/comms/messaging64/lib:/opt/sun/comms/messaging64/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/root/bs`. btw, the changes did not help me. I know i'm pushed you to the limit but i don't understand why this is happening!

Comment: @Karthik Did you use the full path? I'll update the answer

Comment: I used the full path `/opt/sun/comms/messaging64/bin/mboxutil -l > n.txt`. There was no change. It gives me the result when I execute the script directly but while using crontab, it doesn't process.

Comment: @Karthik oh Gosh haha, ok let me know whats does the output.log say, I hope it changed

Comment: `output.log` gives me 4 lines errors. 1. `Can't open /root/scripts/n.txt`. 2. `cat: cannot open /root/scripts/n1.txt`. 3. `Can't open /root/scripts/n2.txt`. 4. `/root/scripts/extract.sh: all-dss-accounts.txt: cannot open`

Comment: just a small doubt, is it necessary to use paths for all the files while will get created. wont the files get created in the same path where the script resides?

Comment: @Karthik ok, this must be a location and/or permissions stuff, try also setting the full paths in all files and check out the file permissions. At least we solved the `mboxutil` issue lol

Comment: @Karthik I haven't heard about you, did you solve your problem?

Comment: I was out sick for a few days. Nope! Its not working. :( I'm doing manual run of the script..

Comment: @Karthik with the full paths modification, what does the output.log say?

Comment: output.log gave me this `/root/scripts/extract.sh: all-dss-accounts.txt: cannot open` `/root/scripts/extract.sh: all-dss-accounts.txt: cannot open`. This time around, the `all-dss-accounts.txt` file was correctly created but the script did not send me an email as expected.

Comment: @Karthik Hmmmmm... try using a different `mail` line like `cat /path/to/all-dss-accounts.txt | mail -s "DSS count on date is $CNT" karthik@email.com`. The `cannot open` could be a file permission issue.

Comment: i used the `mail` line as you suggested above. I received an email with a blank subject. moreover the `output.log` shows this `/root/scripts/extract.sh: all-dss-accounts.txt: cannot open`. My doubt here is how did I receive the contents of all-dss-accounts.txt in the body of the email (as expected) if the script could not open the file.

Comment: @Karthik are you sure the `all-dss-accounts.txt` file has the right readable permission? Try `chmod +r all-dss-accounts.txt `

Comment: yes, permission looks like the issue. direct running the script created the `all-dss-accounts.txt` file with the permission `-rwxr-xr-x`. running the script through crontab created the same file with a different permission `-rw-r--r--`. So, I changed the script, added `chmod +x /root/scripts/all-dss-accounts.txt` after the line which creates the file. Despite this change, the crontab run failed to send me an email. The output.log file has this error `/root/kakanara/extract.sh: all-dss-accounts.txt: cannot open` `/root/kakanara/extract.sh: all-dss-accounts.txt: cannot open`. Why this error??

Comment: @Karthik Does the `all-dss-accounts.txt` file have the complete path? Also make sure the `chmod` line is at the very end of the script. To be sure ...  lets put `chmod 777 /path/to/all-dss-accounts.txt `

Comment: perfect! the changes worked. I made sure the paths were included before the file and chmod included in the end. :)

Comment: @Karthik Good news buddy! you did great!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use full paths to the output files and probably to the executables as well. When run in cron, there is no pre-existing environment for it to know things like a working directory or a path.

Comment: mboxutil -l > /root/scripts/n.txt
sed 's/^.*user//' /root/scripts/n.txt > /root/scripts/n1.txt
cat /root/scripts/n1.txt | sed 's/^.//' > /root/scripts/n2.txt
sed 's/\/.*//' /root/scripts/n2.txt > /root/scripts/dss_list.txt
rm -f /root/scripts/n*.txt

sed -e '/^$/d' -e '1d' /root/scripts/dss_list.txt > /root/scripts/all-dss-accounts.txt
rm -f /root/scripts/dss_list.txt
CNT=`wc -l < /root/scripts/all-dss-accounts.txt`
mailx -s "DSS count on `date` is $CNT" karthik@email.com < /root/scripts/all-dss-accounts.txt

Comment: I used the modified script above. The cron entry ran the script but the last part of the script for taking the count was not working.

`CNT=wc -l < /root/scripts/all-dss-accounts.txt`
.